# http://127.0.0.1:8000/ windows 10 django eclipse blank page

Tags: django, windows

After running my django project in eclipse and entering http://127.0.0.1:8000/ into a web browser the web page appears blank.

There are no error messages reported.

I haven't ran this project since I upgraded to win 10 last month - could this be why it doesn't work no more and if so, how do I resolve this?

I've tried to run other projects that I know used to work and the same thing happens - blank page. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Is your runserver showing something once you start it? Normally it shows the requests made to that dev server.

Comment: [15/Sep/2015 18:55:46]"GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 77630 after I enter 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' into a browser. Nothing else...